# MSSQL PHP could not find driver

Tags: php, html, sql-server, apache, web

as to see in the title i have troubles to connect to a mssql database via php. I tried literally anything, I tried it with Apache, with IIS, 5 different drivers in 2 different locations and the only message i get is "could not find driver". I also defined the drivers in the php.ini file multiple times in multiple combinations and put the dlls in the extensions folder, but nothing seems to work. Currently, I'm trying to connect with the following connection string: `$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=MYSERVER;Database=MYDATABASE", "MYUSER", "MYPASSWORD");`
Please inform me if I can provide any more information, im just frustrated.
Thanks in advance!

**Edit**
I tried to load the extensions directly with `dl("php_pdo_sqlsrv_80_nts.dll");`, but it also didn't work.

Comment: Have you *actually* installed the drivers..? Saying you've defined them doesn't mean anything if you haven't downloaded them.

Comment: Full installation [steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/install-the-sql-server-driver-for-php).

Comment: I downloaded the drivers and put them into the extension folder, then defined them in the php.ini file. I also followed the full installation steps and tried it with xampp, nothing seems to work.

Comment: did you restart apache after changing setup?

Comment: Are you editing the *correct* php.ini file? Xampp and Apache will likely use different php.ini files each.

Comment: Yes, multiple times. When i tried it with IIS, i also restarted it multiple times.

Comment: I edited both files just to be sure.

Comment: You can verify the correct php file you're editing by creating a page with [`phpinfo()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php). Also, in the output of `phpinfo`, can you see the `sqlsrv` modules listed?

Comment: No, theres no "sqlsrv" in the phpinfo.

Comment: Maybe missing Userrights for the user the Apache runs under?